# Use CSS to overlay image on gradient with padding

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-position

I'm attempting to create a button that contains a gradient covering the whole button, then with an image on just a portion of the button.

(note: for ease of the question I've changed my code to a div, but the outcome remains the same)

Initially this was successful doing such:

```
<div class="myBtn_1">test button one</div>

.myBtn_1    
{ 
  border: solid 1px #ff00ff;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/21?image=1080'), 
     linear-gradient(to right, rgba(141, 245, 146, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)); 
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-size:     auto 100%;
  width:               200px;
  height:              50px;
  padding-left:        65px; 
}
```

the jfiddle representing this can be found: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5v6zgr2d/)

HOWEVER I want some border around my image within the button/div, so I added `background-position 5px 5px` to the css, as well as explicitly setting the background-size (auto 40px). This does add padding to the image, but it also adds padding to the gradient.

again, see the 2nd class in the same [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5v6zgr2d/)

**Question:** how can I create a button/div in css that has a gradient covering the full background, then add an image that has padding around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can comma delineate the individual background properties too.

```css
.myBtn_3    
{ 
    border: solid 1px #ff00ff;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/21?image=1080'), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(141, 245, 146, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)); 
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-size:     auto 40px, auto auto;
    width:               200px;
    height:              50px;
    padding-left:        65px;
    background-position: 5px 5px, 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="myBtn_3">
test button two
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect...beat me to it by a *nano*-second. ☺

Comment: simple, and probably exactly what this is for. thank you for taking your time to answer!

Comment: @Paulie_D lol.  Usually I'm on the receiving end of that kind of luck. :P

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
position: absolute;
```

on the image and just put it inside the div

```css
.myBtn_1    
{ 
  border: solid 1px #ff00ff;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/21?image=1080'), 
     linear-gradient(to right, rgba(141, 245, 146, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)); 
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-size:     auto 100%;
  width:               200px;
  height:              50px;
  padding-left:        65px; 
}

.myBtn_2    
{ 
    border: solid 1px #ff00ff;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/21?image=1080'), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(141, 245, 146, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)); 
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-size:     auto 40px;
    width:               200px;
    height:              50px;
    padding-left:        65px;
    background-position: 5px 5px;
}

.myBtn_3  
{ 
    border: solid 1px #ff00ff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(141, 245, 146, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)); 
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-size:     auto 100%;
    width:               200px;
    height:              50px;
    padding-left:        65px;
    position: relative;
}

.myBtn_3 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px)
}
```

```html
     
     
     <div class="myBtn_1">test button one</div>
<br />

<div class="myBtn_2">
     test button two
     </div>
<br />

<div class="myBtn_3">
     test button three
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/21?image=1080">
     </div>
```